# Why when I try to scrollRectToVisible to higher position, it just scroll to highest positions

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm using scrollRectToVisible on my uiScrollView. It works good when I try to scroll below. But when my scroll is below and I try to scroll up it just scroll to position 0 0 not position which I'm use in this method:

```
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 150) animated:YES];
```

It works good when I in position for eg. self.scrollView.frame.size.height but when I on position for eg. self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 300 it scroll to self.scrollView.frame.size.height position.

Comment: I'm not sure i've understood what you meant. But the code you provide will always scroll to top, since the origin is (0,0).

Comment: Have you set your `UIScrollView` `contentSize` height to at least `self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 300` ?

Comment: If you are setting up a paging thing, that is a default property you could set. But with your problem, it's because the I think that + 300 is suppose to be in the Y position of the origin CGRectMake(0, 150, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height) obviously you can't view more of the contents of a scroll view than the width and height of a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method incorrectly. scrollRectToVisible will scroll the scroll view until the entire rect (or most of it), **relative** to the scroll view, is in the 'draw' region of the UIScrollView.

`[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(100, 100, 1, 1) animated:YES];`

Will make the position 100:100, in the scroll view, visible.